# How to use Data-Store in Embedded Gate NLP

Tags: java, nlp, gate

I am new to `Gate Nlp`. I have more than 100 documents to process . But after Processing 20-25 documents , Throws `out of memory exception` . So , I want to use now `datastore` to store the corpus .So that it will release the memory after processing it .I have  a `gapp` file of the application , through which it loads the document . My code is like

```
  if (!Gate.isInitialised()) {
            Gate.runInSandbox(true);
            Gate.init();
        }



        application = (CorpusController) PersistenceManager.loadObjectFromFile(gapFile);
        // Create a Corpus to use.  We recycle the same Corpus object for each
        // iteration.  The string parameter to newCorpus() is simply the
        // GATE-internal name to use for the corpus.  It has no particular
        // significance.
        corpus = Factory.newCorpus(AppConstants.MAIN_CORPUS);
        application.setCorpus(corpus);
        doc = Factory.newDocument(new File(docFilePath).toURI().toURL());
        // put the document in the corpus
        corpus.add(doc);
        // run the application
        application.execute();
        }
```

After this i am deleting the corpus .After deleting also  , it is not clearing the memory .How can i solve this  ?

Answer (score 0):

In your example you have created a corpus without SerialDatastore.
You could find examples of real SerialDatastore usage  [here](https://gate.ac.uk/wiki/code-repository/src/sheffield/examples/DataStoreApplication.java)